# "Uphill" OR "Upslope" in this context

Tags: word-choice

> The road is quite **uphill / upslope** all the way between *A* and *B*.

*(here A and B are name of two places)*

Are the words **uphill** and **upslope** and their opposite **downhill** and **downslope** respectively fine?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1: "Uphill" and "downhill" are absolute, not relative. If B is on land that is higher up than A, it is uphill of A. It can't be "quite uphill", or "very uphill" or "not very uphill". It's either up the hill, or it is not up the hill.

If you want an adjective to describe a change in height, you might use **steep**. You could say

> The road is quite **steep** all the way between A and B.

As you noted in a comment, "steep" does not indicate direction. If you want the direction, you can say

> The road is uphill all the way between A and B.

(without "quite").

If you want both direction and magnitude, you can't really have an intensifier on "uphill", unfortunately, so you would say something like

> The road is steep, and uphill all the way between A and B.

2: I have never seen or heard "upslope" or "downslope".

Comment: But "steep" simply doesn't give the sense that which direction it's going up or down.

Comment: @Kumarsadhu Yes, that's right. Edited my answer with more detail.

Comment: Can the opposite "downhill" be used the same way as "uphill"?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu Yes. Do you have an English dictionary you can use? They should contain that kind of information.